# System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null. in Test Class

Tags: unit-test, null-pointer

At this line I am getting an errror, while running a Test Class, Please suggest solution -

```
public PageReference Save(){
    -------code ------
      Object__c obj = new Object__c();
      obj.my_Date__c=Date.Today();
     insert obj;

       //check here - if holiday Date is on Sat or Sunday --give an error msg
    Date mydate = Date.newInstance(2012,11,1); 
    Datetime dt = DateTime.newInstance(obj.my_Date__c, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0)); 
    String dayOfWeek=dt.format('EEEE');         
      -------code ------
}
```

TEST CLASS :

```
myController controller = new myController();       
        controller.Save();
```

Comment: I need more code to be sure, but it looks like `obj.Mydate()` is null, as `Time.newInstance(...)` should not return null. Are you able to post the rest of your test class and the code for your `Mydate()` method?

Comment: No  I have given obj.MyDate=Date.Tobday(), just before this line

Comment: `obj.Mydate` is different to `obj.Mydate()`, the first is a field and the second is a method. Without more code I don't think anyone is going to be able to give you an answer with any degree of confidence.

Comment: I have edited the question with some more code

Comment: @NileshMendhe - Do us all a favor please and system.debug(obj.MyDate__c) JUST before the line providing the error and let us know the results....

Comment: adding the full stacktrace including the line numbers would help identify the line that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Eric : Its giving me date

Comment: Datetime dt = DateTime.newInstance(obj.my_Date__c, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));
This line needs a Code Coverage - which is the main reason causing an error.

Comment: @NileshMendhe you have changed the code in your question since you raised the question. Are you saying that the current code is still throwing the NullPointerException? If so, please add the full stacktrace including line numbers. It could be a case that a trigger on `Object__c` is causing the problem

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that error is coming out of the code you've posted ?

Comment: @NileshMendhe - If you are indeed getting a valid date then that line will not be throwing an error. A stack trace, debug log, etc would now be required to help you further

Comment: Error Message System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.

Stack Trace Class.MyController.save: line 46, column 1
Class.MyControllerTest.validateMyController: line 27, column 1

Comment: Where Line no 27  = controller.save();
and Line no 46 = 
Datetime dt = DateTime.newInstance(obj.my_Date__c, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply putting this in IF() in my controller's code solved my problem, but I am damn sure I am having a compulsory value in myDate__c.

```
public pageReference save(){
-----code----
 if(objHoliday.Holiday_Date__c!=null){
            Datetime dt = DateTime.newInstance(objHoliday.Holiday_Date__c, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0)); 
            String dayOfWeek=dt.format('EEEE');         
     -----code----
}
 ----code-----
}
```

Comment: Answer was in there only but I was not thinking about null values too much.